# Apache Fluent Authenticator

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

How can I Authenticate with apache fluent api ? 
This code doesn't help me :

```
    CredentialsProvider provider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
UsernamePasswordCredentials credentials
        = new UsernamePasswordCredentials("user1", "user1Pass");
```

provider.setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, credentials);

```
HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create()
        .setDefaultCredentialsProvider(provider)
        .build();
```